# How to optimise this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, xquery

i am new to XQuery.
please suggest a way to optimse below query.

i have tried below query it is taking more time than expected.

```
Select 
A.a_name, 
I.p_type, 
SUM(P.c_n_amount) AS c_n_amount,
CASE  WHEN SUM(ABS(M_value)) = 0 THEN 0
ELSE SUM(ABS(Price) * ABS(M_value)) / SUM(ABS(M_value)) END AS 
[price],
SUM(M_value) AS m_value,SUM(N50) [-50],SUM(P50) [50]
from  position P 
INNER JOIN COUNT AS A ON P.a_id = A.a_id 
INNER JOIN I_VIEW AS I ON P.i_id = I.i_id 
inner join (
select R_C.p_id,M_value,Price,N50,P50
from(
select j.p_id,
C.value('(Result[@resultName = "m_value"]/resultValue)[1]', 'float') as M_value,
C.value('(Result[@resultName = "price"]/resultValue)[1]', 'float') as Price
from  jyothi_xml j CROSS APPLY resultkeys.nodes('/Results')  T(C) 
where r_set='POLY' and r_category ='sk')  R_Category,
(select j1.p_id,
C.value('(Result[@resultName = "rate_shock_n50"]/resultValue)[1]', 'float') as N50,
C.value('(Result[@resultName = "rate_shock_p50"]/resultValue)[1]', 'float') as P50
from jyothi_xml j1 CROSS APPLY resultkeys.nodes('/Results')  T(C)
where result_set='POLY' and result_category ='rate_shocks')  R_S_Category,position p
where p.p_id=R_Category.p_id and p.p_id=R_S_Category.p_id) XMlData  on p.p_id=XMlData.p_id
WHERE P.as_of_date = '2012-10-10' 
GROUP BY A.a_name, I.p_type
```

Comment: What is the data you operate on? And what is your expected result? In general, in XQuery it is benefical to have predicates as early as possible, i.e. instead of (Result[@resultName = "m_value"]/resultValue)[1] use (Result[@resultName = "m_value"][1]/resultValue).
However, I guess that XQuery is not the bottleneck here. Instead, you have a quite costly SQL with joins, aggregations and subquerys. In comparison, your XQuery seems to be simple data extraction. Please check first, that XQuery is really the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of XML to parse through, it is very beneficial to first limit which rows with XML you need, then parse through them.  So, if you can, figure out what you need from your Position, Count, and I_View tables and then just search for those IDs in the jyothi_xml table.  I found that this helps a lot with my queries.